# Button showing up in top left

Tags: android

The button I made is in the center of the design screen, but when I run the app it is showing up in the top left.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="148dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="231dp" />
```

Comment: you might wanna try `layout_gravity=center`

Comment: When asking a question like this, you should include information about the view's parent. The correct solution changes if the button is inside a `FrameLayout`, a `RelativeLayout`, or a `ConstraintLayout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using `ConstraintLayout`? The problem is these attributes:

```
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="148dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="231dp"
```

`tools` attributes affect how a view looks in the Android Studio preview, but have no effect on how it looks when you actually run the app. You will need to add constraints to your button if you want it to be centered when you run. Add these:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Answer (score 1):

ZeekHuge is right, here try this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Button"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="148dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="231dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This view is not constrained, it only has designtime positions, so it will jump to **(0,0)** unless you add constraints.
The layout editor allows you to place widgets anywhere on the canvas, and it records the current position with **designtime attributes** (such as layout_editor_absoluteX.) 
These attributes are not applied at runtime, so if you push your layout on a device, the widgets may appear in a different location than shown in the editor. 
**To fix this**, make sure a widget has both horizontal and vertical constraints by dragging from the edge connections.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="148dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="231dp"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

 />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Center Btn"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```